# populate listview from db

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

I'm trying to populate wpf listview from database using ado.net. I have this code:

```
private void Window_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowData(); 
}

public void ShowData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=mySource;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True");

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select book.ID_book, book.book, book.ID_autor, book.genre from book", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        data.Fill(dt);
        ListView1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error connection to database", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? It's not my connection's fault

and here's my listview xaml:

```
<ListView Canvas.Left="243" Canvas.Top="41" Canvas.Right="0"  
                  Width="262"  
                  Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}" 
                  MinWidth="250" MinHeight="100" Height="182" Margin="1"
                  >
            <ListView.View>
```

Comment: Do you obtain any exception? Which one? What is wrong?

Comment: not. it simple does not populate

Comment: in your Window_loaded code.. have you tried to set ItemSource property instead of DataContext

Comment: Your xaml is wrong, it has `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: I'm changed it but didn't solve my problem

Comment: @IlVic I would have edit the typo, it may be an error from the OP...